# Change series name order

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, highcharts

I'm trying to create a chart with some information, at the moment I'm able to display all the information from my database table and then create a chart but I have a problem, the order from my series name (created with an array) is different as the order in the array. In the below picture is the example of what I have at the moment.

[image]

What I expect is to display the series name in the same order as the array result showed at the browser console.

This is what I use to draw my chart.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'Chart',
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: nombre
            },
            xAxis: {
                labels:
                   {
                       enabled: false
                   }
            },
            yAxis: {
                allowDecimals: true,
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Piezas'
                },
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            legend: {
                reversed: true
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        format: '{point.y}'
                    }
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:11px">{series.name}</span><br>',
                pointFormat: '<span style="color:{point.color}">{point.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> piezas<br/>'
            },

            series: []
        });

        for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            chart.addSeries({
            name: arreglo[i],
            data: [arreglo2[i]],
        }, false);
    }
    chart.reflow();
    chart.redraw(); 
    $('#AreaGrafica').removeClass('hidden');
    window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
```

Comment: Just remove `legend: {reversed: true},`

Comment: @Core972 hahaha!! I didn't see that... thanks a lot!!!